When closing Blender and reopening all my animation disappears
Every time I close and reopen a project on blender all added colours, textures, and fire animations delete along with the nodes, but all the objects are still in the project, how would I fix this?

"added colours, textures and fire animations" - and with "fire animations" you mean smoke/fire simulations? Have you baked the simulations? And how/where did you "add" colors and textures?

Yes I baked the simulations and the colours were added as nodes that have disappeared
